# S parameter meaning

Tags: rf, antenna, pcb-antenna

I have designed a rectangular patch antenna and have tested it. From the results I noted a value of - 25dB on the
S11 parameter graph. The - 25dB is also at my resonant frequency of 915MHz. Is this a reasonable value for a patch antenna?

The application for this antenna is in the RFID sector.

It has a gain of 2.5dBi and measures at 20x20cm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S11 is the return loss.  -25 dB is very good for a return loss parameter, almost too good to be true.  This means that only 0.3% of the input power is reflected back to the source, and implies an almost perfect impedance match at the input to your patch.

Comment: How did you calculate the 0.3%?

Comment: Just converted -25 dB to a power ratio.